# Convert Olson timezone id to GMT +/- X

Tags: perl, timezone

I save epoch timestamps and visitor timezones are saved as the Olson id, eg Europe/London

```
 if($userTz && $userTz ne "Europe/London"){
    $ENV{TZ} = "$userTz";
 }

($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($time);
...
```

Once the epoch is displayed in the relevant timezone I want to place after the date/time what the timezone is. Example  GMT+4 instead of Asia/Muscat (using GMT+4 example)

Comment: Have you made an attempt to find out by using the Perl documentation or Google?  In other words, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I did, Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [DateTime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime)/[DateTime::TimeZone](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aTimeZone).

Offset in seconds (also see the related methods [offset_as_seconds](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aTimeZone#DateTime%3a%3aTimeZone-offset_as_seconds-offset-) and [offset_as_string](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aTimeZone#DateTime%3a%3aTimeZone-offset_as_string-offset-)):

```
DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => 'Asia/Muscat')->offset_for_datetime(DateTime->now)
# 14400
```

ISO 8601/RFC 3339 specifier

```
DateTime->now(time_zone => 'Asia/Muscat')->strftime('%z')
# '+0400'
```

---

*GMT±X* is non-standard, do not expect any system or software to interoperate with this notation. How do you express zones that are not full-hour offsets, like Asia/Tehran, in that scheme? The current system is based on UTC, anyway: http://enwp.org/UTC%2B04:00. A naïve implementation could mangle one of the values from above.

Comment: You can do `DateTime->now(time_zone => 'Asia/Muscat')` instead of `DateTime->now->set_time_zone('Asia/Muscat')`. Doesn't matter much for `now`, but it makes a lot of difference for `today`.

Comment: If GMT is now UTC, how does UTC handle 1/2 hours? I expect it's say +04:30 I'm happy to use the correct standard but didn't want Asia/Muscat. I'd prefer a UTC offset or ISO country code equivalent as it's shorter to display. The actual timestamp is saved in the database as GMT, my local timezone also the same zone as UTC with some leep seconds no doubt. It's the display date so interoperability isn't an issue here